# present perfect or past simple?!/Third conditional or mixed conditional

Tags: verbs, conditional-constructions

which one of these sentences is correct?!

> 1)You shouldn't have gone to the cinema yesterday.
>   2)you shouldn't went to the cinema yesterday.

To me sentence 1 sounds better than the second one,but the fact that when we are refering to a specific time( here **yesterday**) we must use past simple kinda made me confused;and the other thing is that as far as I remember I've never heard using should/shouldn't with the past form of the verbs.
What if I want to use conditionals for expressing the same thing:which one should I use?!

> 1)It would have been better if you hadn't gone to the cinema
>   2)It would have been better if you didn't go to the cinema

To me third conditionl(first sentence) sounds more logical than the mixed conditional but I'm still not sure

Comment: Idiomatically, native speakers (especially *Brits*) often omit the article when talking about going to ***work, school, hospital,*** etc., but I don't know of any region where competent speakers would do this when talking about *going to **the** cinema*. Your case #2 (if you ***didn't go***) strongly implies a possible ***future*** act that you're being advised to avoid doing (or in a slightly contrived context, a ***habitual*** activity). But ***hadn't gone*** unambiguously entails the fact that you did in fact go - albeit unwisely, so far as the speaker is concerned.

Comment: @FumbleFingersYes,that's true.Now that I've checked cinema in my dictionary I couldn't find any examples that articles weren't used but as a non-native speaker I've heard it alot.What about the verb tenses used in my two first examples which one is correct?present perfect or past simple?!

Comment: Some (badly-educated) dialectal speakers might say things like *I shouldn't have went to work yesterday,* but it's very uncommon and would generally be considered "ignorant". Standard English requires ***gone*** there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers sorry I think I must have misunderstood you.What you mean is the only thing that I can say in this case is,It would have been better if you hadn't gone to the cinema and neither You **shouldn't have gone** to the cinema nor You **shouldn't went** to cinema is correct.Is it right?!

Comment: @anonymous - No, FumbleFingers is saying that **shouldn't went** is wrong, **shouldn't have went** is wrong, and **shouldn't have gone** IS correct.

Comment: @stangdon: I mentioned "habitual activity" as a possible contrived context where *...if you **didn't** go to the cinema* would be acceptable (implying that *going to the cinema* is "timeless" (it's one of your past / present / future activities). Something similar applies with, say, *It was a good movie, but it would have been better if I **didn't know** the ending* - which I find a bit awkward (it should be ***hadn't known***), but it does imply greater relevance to time of speaking (I knew how the movie would end when I watched it, but my knowing this is ***still significant now***).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal verbs can't combine with past tense forms.  You can't say "should *went*", "might *went*", "should *stayed*", "will *walked*", "can *listened*".

Modal verbs are followed by **infinitives**: "should *go*", "might *go*", "should *stay*", "will *walk*", "can *listen*".

They can also be followed by **perfect infinitives**: "should *have gone*", "might *have gone*", "should *have stayed*", "will *have walked*".

They cannot be followed by finite or tensed verbs such as "went" or "goes".

So, of your two sentences:

> 1) You **shouldn't have gone** to the cinema yesterday.
>
> 2) *You **shouldn't went** to the cinema yesterday.

The second option is ungrammatical, because "should went" and "shouldn't went" are ungrammatical.  Nothing to do with sequence of tenses or numbered conditionals.  Option 1 is the only one available.  (If you were speaking to a time-traveller, you could also use "You shouldn't go to the cinema yesterday" to advise them on what to do yesterday.)

As for your next example:

> 1) It would have been better if you **hadn't gone** to the cinema
>
> 2) It would have been better if you **didn't go** to the cinema

Option 1 is far more likely because you're presumably talking about the past.  If you were talking about someone's habit of going to the cinema, and saying that if they didn't have that cinema-going habit then things would have turned out better, then you could use option 2.